# How to run Windows 10 at much higher resolution than my monitor supports? Virtual desktop?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop, high-resolution

Is there a way to run Windows with a very large desktop (equivalent of 3 screens) and then scroll around to view the parts that I want to see.

Put another way, is there a way to recreate having a PC with multiple screens without having the multiple screens.  We are connecting to work with PC (3 screens) from home PC (1 screen) and really like the experience (GoToMyPC) of being able to switch between 3 screens.  I want to recreate on home PC without actually attaching multiple monitors or running GTMPC.

Any software that allows this?

Comment: Windows 10 has virtual desktops: https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/virtual-desktop-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why essjae commented rather than answered, but yeah, try out [virtual desktops](https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/virtual-desktop-windows-10) (Win-Tab also gets you there). It doesn't do scrolling, but you can switch between workspaces, which is similar to switching between monitors in (for example) Splashtop or LogMeIn.